# IIS 7 many website in one ip address

Tags: iis, iis-7, web, windows-server-2008

I use IIS 7 and when I create new website I wont one IP adress. But I have one. I want this http/ipadress/mywebsite
how to do it?

thanks

Comment: You will need to make your question clearer, it's difficult to understand what you're after. Is it that you want all your websites to be accessed via the same IP address rather than using domain names for them? Perhaps give us a few examples of the type of web address format you want to see.

Comment: np. http/111.111.111.111/mywebsite1  or http/111.111.111.111/mywebsite2 ...

Answer (score 3):

sorry if there's a better way to show this, but this was already answered here...

[multiple sites on IIS7 under the same URL and port but on different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297632/multiple-sites-on-iis7-under-the-same-url-and-port-but-on-different-directories)