# Blazor server Wrong navigation

Tags: asp.net, .net, navigation, blazor

I deploy web apps on Windows Server 2016 using IIS. Created a new website here and I want to host 2 apps. When I run the app it opens on `localhost:90/appname/`, but when I redirect to `/login` it goes to localhost:90/login instead of `localhost:90/appname/login`. (On `localhost:90/login` page doesn't exist)
Also, the appname name could change, so I need to change something in the code to fix it

Tried changing the base href, but appname could be changed; so it doesn't work.

Comment: One possible solution is to convert the two subdirectory into separate IIS applications. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297632/multiple-sites-on-iis7-under-the-same-url-and-port-but-on-different-directories